# Controller Area Network (CAN) has got a constant or variable bit rate?

Tags: can-bus

I'm wondering if the following question in the Title if the Controller Area Network has got a constant bit rate on the bus or not?

I know that the bit rate is dependent on the synchronization segment, propagation time segment, phase buffer segment 1 and phase buffer segment 2 - but it defines the whole constant bit rate on the bus or the selected device?

All the best

Comment: CAN 2.0 or CAN FD?

Comment: CAN 2.0 for example.

Comment: @LiorKogan more precisely - SPI has the constant bit rate, I2C not because sometimes the slave can slower the transmission, One-wire I supposed that also is not constant because of the fact the data is transmitted in the 60-120 us slots and I', wondering if the CAN bus has constant or variable bit rate.

Comment: @bolko What you mentioned about I2C is *clock stretching*, and it can't be considered as a bit rate change.

Comment: @Tagli so I2C has a constant bit rate?

Comment: Well, master controls the clock so in theory it's possible that master can change it too, as long as it remains within the limits of the slaves on the bus. But I have never heard of such an application. It doesn't make sense to change bit rate of the I2C bus, because most of the time it's used for communication of the on-board components.

Comment: "but it defines the whole constant bit rate on the bus or the selected device?" Data communication fundamentals: all nodes involved in the communication must use the same baudrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic CAN Bus (2.0) has constant bit rate. But the bit rate isn't the only property of the bus. Position of the sampling is also important, and must be same for all devices on the bus. Common positions for the bit sampling time is 75% or 87.5%, but it can vary according to the application. Also, CAN hardware of the nodes can slightly modify this value automatically.

But again, the bit rate is constant, only the position of the sampling within the bit time period can change a little bit.

CAN FD is different. Data segment of the frame can be sent with a different bit rate.